# Backbone event triggering and event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone. I just want to know about the global event triggering and bind the callback for each event. I've tried like this...

**landing.view.js**

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
var tpl = require('text!components/landing-page/templates/landing-page.html');

return Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.view-container',

    template: _.template($(tpl).html()),

    events:{
        'click .btn-show': 'showUsersListHandler'
    },

    initialize: function(){

        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){

        $(this.el).html(this.template);
        return this;
    },

    showUsersListHandler: function(evt){   
        Backbone.trigger('userPage', {trigger:true});
    }
});
```

**another.view.js**

```
'use strict';

var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery');
var tpl = require('text!components/user-logs-listing/templates/user-logs-listing-tpl.html');

return Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.users-list-container',

    template: _.template($(tpl).html()),

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){

        $(this.el).html(this.template);
    }

});
```

**app-router**

'use strict';

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var viewContainer = require('inits/utils');
var landingView = require('components/landing-page/views/landing-page');
var userListingView = require('components/user-logs-listing/views/user-logs-listing.view');

return Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "landing",
        "usersList": "usersPage"
        //'*path':  'defaultRoute'
    },

    initailize: function(){ 
    Backbone.listenTo(Backbone, 'userPage', this.usersPage)

    },

    landing: function(){

        viewContainer.createContainer('view-container');
        new landingView();
    },

    usersPage: function(){

        //$('.view-container').remove();
        viewContainer.createContainer('users-list-container');
        new userListingView();
    }
});
```

If I click the button in the landing view, it should trigger that 'userPage' and it should navigate to #UsersPage. The issue is how to trigger and bind the callback for global events ???? Help me to get the correct solution!!! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by global events?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if I'm not wrong, when I trigger 'userPage' event in the landing view the another view should be render. I have attached the event response in the Router, but it wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will suggest to do it like this:

Make a new file Events.js

**Events.js**

```
define(['underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  "use strict";
  return _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
});
```

Now, in **landing.view.js**

```
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var Events = require('Events');
    var tpl = require('text!components/landing-page/templates/landing-page.html');

-----
    Events.on('customEvent1',this.customCallback1);
-----
```

Similarly, in **another.view.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Events = require('Events');
var $ = require('jquery');
var tpl = require('text!components/user-logs-listing/templates/user-logs-listing-tpl.html');

-----
    Events.on('customEvent2',this.customCallback2);
-----
```

Now, anywhere you want to trigger these custom events, do as:

```
Events.trigger('customEvent1');

Events.trigger('customEvent2');
```

And include Events file whereever you want to use it.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This method I've tried already, not working!!! The issue is, the events attached in the listeners was not getting register in the 'Backbone._events' (i.e., trigger function)